# Ubuntu Mate Not Installing!

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I have been trying to install ubuntu mate on my Hp Pavilion g6

Legacy Boot is Disabled

Secure Boot is Disabled

I get that option of try ubuntu,install ubuntu etc

after that just a black screen appears.

Ps:- I have tried this on my other laptop and it has worked flawlessly. 
I have a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS already on the hp laptop.